# Bash: How to pass a variable to a command

Tags: bash, date

I need to substract 10 minutes from a given time.

As I understand from previous answers, there are solutions **only** for given constant input, for example:

```
date --date '20140202 11:45:30 UTC -10 min'
```

But in my script, a given date is read from file and I have it as argument, for example:

```
myDate="20140202 11:45:30"
```

How can I pass this argument `(myDate)`to the command above?

Comment: Double quotes and as a variable.

Comment: Read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 0):

```
myDate="20140202 11:45:30"
date --date "${myDate} UTC -10 min"
```